# What does "Ballet girl, Oriental type" mean in food context?

Tags: meaning

Levin and Oblonsky are sitting face to face:

> Levin: Have you stopped stealing bread rolls?
>
> Oblonsky: **Ballet girl, Oriental type**. How can I help it?

What does "Ballet girl, Oriental type" mean in food context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oblonsky makes this statement to explain why she steals rolls, but it's less about the food and more about describing herself. She desires the rolls probably because the exercise ballet dancers perform causes them to crave more calories, but ballet dancers also need to watch their weight or their dance partners will complain when lifting them off the ground. The 'oriental type' just means she is a ballet dancer with oriental genes or ancestors.